# How to set the private property of a class instance individually?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to set the properties of the class instance in the Provider class individually. But I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Can you kindly advise how can go about doing it?

```
void main() { 
  Provider userprovider = Provider();
  userprovider.setUsername='johncena';
  userprovider.setEmail='hello@gmail.com';

  print(userprovider.getUser.username);
  print(userprovider.getUser.email
}


class Provider {
  User _user;
  User get getUser => _user;

  set setUsername(username){
    _user.name = username;
  }

  set setEmail(email){
    _user.email = email;
  }
}


class User {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String email;
  String username;
  String status;
  int state;
  String profilePhoto;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.username,
    this.status,
    this.state,
    this.profilePhoto,
  });
}
```

The current error I'm seeing on Dartpad is :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set$name' of nullError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set$name' of null

edit below-----

To give you some context, I'm building an onboarding page on Flutter where users will be brought first to fill in his username and he will then be pushed to the next widget, date of birth, etc.

I'm planning to store the data locally as the user moves from the first to the last widget and only pushes the accumulated data as a class altogether, User(username: xyz, date of birth: 11/11/2001, gender: male, interest: tennis).

However, I'm unsure of how to set the individual properties of the _user instance in the Provider class

Comment: Where do you give _user a value in Provider?

Comment: yes, I missed that out. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
void main() {
  Provider provider = Provider();
  provider.name = 'John Cena';
  provider.age = 40;

  print(provider.user.name); // Prints 'John Cena'
  print(provider.user.age); // Prints 40
}

class Provider {
  final User _user = User();
  User get user => _user;

  set name(String name) => _user.name = name;

  set age(int age) => _user.age = age;
}

class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User({this.name, this.age});
}
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to add the properties individually, without erasing the previous properties you added? For example, Provider provider = Provider(
    User(username: 'johncena'
  ); and Provider provider = Provider(
    User(email: 'hello@gmail.com'),
  );

Comment: Context: I'm building an onboarding page on Flutter where users will be brought first to fill their username then be pushed to the next widget, email, etc.
As such, I would like to be able to add properties to the _user instance as I move to the next widget.

Comment: And I realised for the code that you sent, you can do without the  
set setUsername(username) {
    _user.name = username;
  }

  set setEmail(email) {
    _user.email = email;
  }
and the code will still work. Do you mind explaining to me when is setter required?

Comment: @scottlee The way I wrote the previous code is generally used as a model for `provider` package. I edited my post to reflect yours, you can now see it works the way you wanted it to work!

Comment: Thank you! You help me solved the problem.